# Parse formatted text and extract two values

Tags: php, arrays, regex, file, text-extraction

How do I get the percentage and filesize from this sort of string using regex in PHP?

The thing is I get this string using the `print_r()` function like so:

```
while(!feof($handle))
{
    $progress = fread($handle, 8192);
    print_r($progress); 
}
```

The above outputs something like this:

```
[download] 28.8% of 1.51M at 171.30k/s ETA 00:06
```

I'm sure I need to use something like `preg_match()` but not sure how to do it for an array plus how do I reference the string. The regex needs to be placed inside the loop.

Comment: How are 100% and 0% represended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($progress as $str) {
    if (preg_match_all('/\[download] (\d+\.\d)% of (\d+\.\d+\w)/', $str, $matches)) {
        var_dump($matches);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation so that this page can be used to helpfully close future questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '[download] 28.8% of 1.51M at 171.30k/s ETA 00:06
           [download] 41.8% of 1.51M at 178.19k/s ETA 00:05';

// $string = file_get_contents($file_path);

$pattern = '/(?<percent>[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2})% of (?<filesize>.+) at/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: (?<percent>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{0,2})?)%

Comment: For some reason I thought I was dealing with time units, where for example 09:60 is actually 10:00

Answer (score 0):

You can also just use:

```
$parts = explode(' ', trim($progress));
$progressPercentage = floatval($parts[1]);
```

It's probably faster than a regex, and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Because your string is predictably formatted and the focus is to extract instead of validate, I agree with @gitaarik in that `explode()` can be suitable.

Split the string on spaces and after you have all of the desired elements, add one more element to the explosion limit so that all of the "leftovers" are slopped into the that last element.

Using [array destructuring syntax](https://stitcher.io/blog/array-destructuring-with-list-in-php), you can declare only the variables that you intend to use.

The benefits will be code performance, readability, and no regex knowledge is necessary.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JNlFA))

```
$string = '[download] 28.8% of 1.51M at 171.30k/s ETA 00:06';
// splits: 0--------| 1---| 2| 3---| 4--------------------| 
[, $percent, , $size, ] = explode(' ', $string, 5);
var_export(['percent' => $percent, 'size' => $size]);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'percent' => '28.8%',
  'size' => '1.51M',
)
```